# Echo the ID of a clicked link using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, variables

This successfully gives an alert for the current clicked link's ID.

```
jQuery('a.inline').live('click',function() {
 jQuery(this).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
 alert(this.id);
});
```

However, instead of getting an alert, i was it to update a variable on that page that i can echo. For example i would like to use something like this ...

```
<p><?php echo $theechoedid; ?></p>
```

I don't really want to be able to echo this as a value of a div, as i'll be using the echo'd value in a loop like so:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'p' => '424', 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) ); ?>
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: If you want to refresh the page, you can send the href via post using a hidden input. If you want to run the PHP without refreshing, you will need a little bit of ajax in your life

Comment: I tried with ajax but couldn't get my head around it. Any pointers? Could i not just use onkeyup or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you don't actually need php for this.  Just use javascript to change the content.

Add an id to the html so it's easier to grab ..

```
<p id="id-goes-here"></p>
```

.. then change it.

```
jQuery('a.inline').live('click',function() {
    jQuery(this).attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
    jQuery( "#id-goes-here" ).html( this.id );
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I've edited my original post to shed more light.

Answer (score 0):

Link 1
Link 2

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.temp).bind('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id');
  }
});
```

This should work.

Justin

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I've edited my original post to shed more light.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use an Ajax call in the end. Thanks for everyones help though.